# Select rows with same id but different value in another column with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to show a list where the id that are duplicated have differents values in another column, a example:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaMsv.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a new table. From the Data tab, click on New Table and input the following code in the prompt:

Duplicatedvalue = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Table'[ID], 'Table'[Value])

Replace Table with the correct name of the table.

Comment: This will return ID=3 too, which isn't the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Then what you can do is to add a column to the source table concatenating ID and value, then creating a visual with the ID, the value and a distinct count of the newly created columns filtered for values >=2